# achemso invalid values for manuscript option

Tags: class-options, achemso

I am using the `manuscript` option `achemso` package, as described [here (page 3)](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso/achemso.pdf). I would like to use it in the following manner:

```
\documentclass[journal=jprobs,manuscript=note,layout=twocolumn,email=true]{achemso}
```

There are several possible values for the `manuscript` option: `article`, `review`, `note`, `communication`, `letter` and `perspective` as well as `suppinfo`. Only the first two seem to work, the others produce an "invalid manuscript type" warning and revert to the default.

Now, the documentation states that "the valid values will depend on the value of journal" but I have examples of (technical) note publications in JPR, so I assume this option should be available.

How do I produce a JPR technical note publication using the `achemso` package?

Comment: The `achemso-jprobs.cfg` definition in the [source](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/achemso/achemso.dtx) contains `\def\acs@type@list{article,review,suppinfo}`, which could mean that the option is not available - but maybe it means something else :)

Answer (score 1):

The list of allowed types is based on what I can pick up for different journals: I can adjust but for the present you are likely best using `article`. (Each journal has its own list.)

Comment: Thanks! I will use `article`. I assume ACS/JPR will reformat my stuff anyways since the LaTeX PDF looks nothing like what the publications end up looking like. I'm new to all this stuff :-)